# Meteor multiple servers to one database collection (local)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, npm

I have a meteor project that does several external API calls on different setInterval() timers and pushes the data to MongoDB.

I want to split the calls to several "micro-services" , different instances running API calls on their own server.

All the data is stored in one single collection

I've found this solution `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor meteor run` but it just gives me errors

How can i connect two meteor server instances to connect to the same collection on the default localhost:3001 database?

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\Nico\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "meteor"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! crypto@ meteor: `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor meteor run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crypto@ meteor script 'export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor meteor'.
```

Comment: Not sure what `crypto@ meteor` is but I think `set MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor & meteor run` should work on windows (`export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor && meteor run` on Mac/Linux). Although I'd install a local mongodb instance separate to Meteor so that you don't have to be running the primary app to be able to access the database (then just change the port 3001 in your command to 27017 or whatever port you run Mongo on).

Comment: Yeah so apparently meteor doesn't start MongoDB when you provide a MONGO_URL environment variable. Therefore it can never connect to the meteor mongo instance at 3001.

So yes directing meteor to a new database on the native 27017 server and running a mongod instance did the job.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Meteor does not start up MongoDB itself when providing a MONGO_URL environment variable.

We need to set MONGO_URL to 27017 port instead of 3001